# Cant get button to work

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Im having this problem where my button wouldnt let me open the URL given. It simply force closes whenever I open this activity. Heres my code;

```
public class TemakiActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contentviewer);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.videolink);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.videothumb);

    addListenerOnButton();

}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videolink);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent browserIntent = 
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

        }

    });

    TextView helloTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.ingredientslister);
    helloTxt.setText(readTxt());
}

private String readTxt(){

 InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.temakiingredients);
 ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

 int i;
try {
i = inputStream.read();
while (i != -1)
  {
   byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
   i = inputStream.read();
  }
  inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

 return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
}
}
```

When I open this activity it simply force closes! Problem seems to be with the button, I cant get it to work, any solutions?

Comment: I rewrote the code and this is what I get with setOnClickListener:The method setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener) in the type View is not applicable for the arguments (new OnClickListener(){})

Comment: Could you show us your import statements ?

Comment: Looks like a ClassCastException. Because in the onCreate-Method you create the "R.id.videolink" object as an Imageview.
Later in the addListenerOnButton-Method you create the same object as a Button. Thats definitely wrong.

Comment: It seems that you imported a wrog OnClickListener.

Comment: Any exception-related questions should be accompanied by a logcat, otherwise you just keep people guessing what is the real mistake in your code!

Comment: post your error please for specific solution

Comment: Thanks for the comments, another issue seems to be within that ImageView line. I cant cast a button with ImageView..

Comment: Okay, thanks for the infos. I will mind myself for the next times to post the error log. Thanks all!

Comment: Thank you for downvoting an appropriate answer.

Comment: mseo I didnt downvote your answer :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have same id for ImageView, and for Button. You must have different id's or you have typed by mistake. The compiler gives error because of conflict of id's.
you have ImageView findViewById(R.id.videolink)
Button findViewById(R.id.videolink);

Comment: The compiler doesn't care. This leads to a class cast exception at runtime.

Comment: Dany is right, it was within that line! Thanks Dany, yeah I mistiped the ID. Sorry to the others for posting this stupid situation!

Answer (score 1):

See you use

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.videolink);
```

Check the button's id because you are using same Id with the `Button` and the `ImageView` 
check which control has `videolink` id ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
```

I think you need to use `Button.OnClickListener()` ;p

Answer (score -1):

Looks like something is wrong with your imports.

Try something like this:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Comment: I didnt downvote it, but i accepted danys answer cause it was more complete. Im sorry :(